# javascript in IE7, number (integer) validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

```
function isInteger(char) {
    return (char.toString().search(/^-?[0-9]+$/) == 0 )
}
function validateQuan() {
var minExist = "false";
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        var j = document.getElementById("ProductQuantity_"+i).value; 
        if (isInteger(j) && j > 0) {minExist = "true";alert("oi");} 
    }
    if (minExist == "true") {$("#pvs_form").submit();} else {alert("Please enter at least one valid quantity");}
}
```

Above is my code, it's working on FF 3.6 and IE8, but not with IE7.
At IE7 "`if (isInteger(j) && j > 0)`" couldn't lead to "true".
Even i remove "`j > 0`" and use "`[1-9]`" on regex.

Any better solution?

**edit** : sorry, the regex is wrong, any number `> 9` is "true" too.

**edit** : big sorry to all, i just found that the main problem actually because i got other form at the same page with the same id "`ProductQuantity_`"+i, and likely it turn the IE7 to only look at the first element with that id found on page. 
Maybe my original code was working actually, but thx to remind me that the regex is not as expected and to get better code. Thx and sorry once more.

Comment: Well, what is `j`? You want `[0-9]` (or `\d`) in the regex. At least that is less incorrect. `[1-9]` wouldn't match `"10"`. And what is up with `"true"` and `"false"`? :(

Comment: ok sorry, "j" will contain text-box's value on the html. I expect it to be valid number and not "0".

Comment: But is it -- `j` -- really what you expect?

Comment: great, thx, i miss that, i just get that regex format from other sites. true and false only for post submit, that's not the part of my question actually, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var isInteger = function( str ) { 
      return  (str|0) == str;
    };
```

Bitwise OR by 0 ensure that, string or number with floating point is replaced to integer

```
isInteger("3.4") // false
isInteger("abc") // false => "abc"|0 = 0
isInteger("3") // true
```

And now:

```
function validateQuan() {
    var minExist = false ;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        var j = document.getElementById("ProductQuantity_"+i).value; 
        if ( isInteger( j ) && j > 0 ) {
            minExist = true; 
            alert("oi");
            break; // goal achieved, break loop
        } 
    }
    if ( minExist ) {
        $("#pvs_form").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Please enter at least one valid quantity");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function validateQuan() {
    var minExist = "false";
    for( i=0; i<3; i++) {
        var j = parseInt(document.getElementById("ProductQuantity_"+i).value);
        if( !isNaN(j) && j > 0) {minExist = "true"; alert("oi");}
    }
    if( minExist == "true") {...} else {...}
}
```

Comment: I would probably add error handling code, but this is the right track IMHO.

Comment: But that doesn't check if the value is an integer, it checks if the value _starts_ with an integer. E.g., `parseInt("123abc")` returns `123`.

Comment: That is true, @nnnnnn, but try typing a letter into a numeric field in an application, and it acts as if the letters aren't there.

Comment: That depends on the application. Some give an error message. Some don't let you type non-numeric characters in the first place (i.e., they never actually appear in the field). And some ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function isInteger(char) {
    return Number(char) == parseInt(char);
}
```